# How to describe a property including inverseOf to an instance in OWL-RDF/XML syntax?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl

I have object properties named `employ` and `employedBy` as they are inverse of each other. How to give these properties to an instance? My `employ` property:

```xml
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="employ">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/" />
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/"/>
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

My `employedBy` property:

```xml
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="employedBy">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/" />
  <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="#Employ" />
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/"/>
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

now how to describe `employ` and `employedBy` in this instance? Assume Pozitron employs john and john is employed by Pozitron.

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/john">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/"/>
  <person:personName>John</person:personName>
  <organization:organizationName>Pozitron</organization:organizationName>
</rdf:Description>
```

Comment: In your data, `john` has an `organizationName` of `"Pozitron`".  Should `john` have an organization name at all?  Should there be an organization `Pozitron` with that name instead?

Comment: As advised in a previous question: use Turtle. Stop using RDF/XML. You're only making life harder for yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's much easier to author RDF in a syntax like Turtle than RDF/XML.  The data you've provided isn't enough for us to work with (e.g., the base URI is undefined).  Here's a complete RDF/XML document with your data (note the `ex` namespace):

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:person="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/"
    xmlns:organization="http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/"
    xml:base="http://example.org/"
    xmlns:ex="http://example.org/#">
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="employ">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/" />
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="employedBy">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/" />
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="#Employ" />
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/john">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/"/>
    <person:personName>John</person:personName>
    <organization:organizationName>Pozitron</organization:organizationName>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

In Turtle, this is the following, and several problems are revealed:

```
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix ex:      <http://example.org/#> .
@prefix person:  <http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/> .
@prefix organization:  <http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

ex:employedBy
      a       person: , owl:ObjectProperty ;
      rdfs:domain person: ;
      rdfs:range organization: ;
      owl:inverseOf ex:Employ .

person:john
      a       person: ;
      organization:organizationName
              "Pozitron" ;
      person:personName "John" .

ex:employ
      a       owl:ObjectProperty , organization: ;
      rdfs:domain organization: ;
      rdfs:range person: .
```

The problems here are that:

- `employedBy`'s inverse is `Employ`, but there's no property by that name, only `employ`;
- the property `employ` is an `organization`
- the property `employedBy` is a `person`
- `john` has an `organizationName`
- there is no organization `Pozitron`.

These are easy to fix in this syntax.  We can also add the triples that `john employedBy Pozitron` and `Pozitron employ john` while we're doing this.  We end up with:

```
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix ex:      <http://example.org/#> .
@prefix person:  <http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/> .
@prefix organization:  <http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

ex:employedBy
      a       owl:ObjectProperty ;
      rdfs:domain person: ;
      rdfs:range organization: ;
      owl:inverseOf ex:employ .

organization:Pozitron
      a       organization: ;
      organization:organizationName
              "Pozitron" ;
      ex:employ person:john .

person:john
      a       person: ;
      person:personName "John" ;
      ex:employedBy organization:Pozitron .

ex:employ
      a       owl:ObjectProperty ;
      rdfs:domain organization: ;
      rdfs:range person: .
```

We can see what this looks like in RDF/XML too by converting it back:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:ex="http://example.org/#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:person="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/"
    xmlns:organization="http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/#employedBy">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#ObjectProperty"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="http://example.org/#employ"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/Pozitron">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/"/>
    <organization:organizationName>Pozitron</organization:organizationName>
    <ex:employ rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/john"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/john">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/"/>
    <person:personName>John</person:personName>
    <ex:employedBy rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/Pozitron"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/#employ">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#ObjectProperty"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/organizations/"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://rdf.pozitron.com/people/"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

If you're using an OWL reasoner that can handle the inverse properties, you really don't need to write both `john employedBy Pozitron` *and* `Pozitron employ john`; you can write just one and the reasoner will infer the other.